# Procedure UNION on tables

Tags: mysql, union, procedure

How can I UNION all results from **stmtQuery** to ONE RESULTS example results from table basia and Comments_11 .... etc

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SearchUserY $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SearchUserY`(IN UserIdValue INT(11) )
BEGIN
       DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
       DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(50);
       DECLARE stmtFields TEXT ; 
       DECLARE columnName VARCHAR(50) default 'UserId';

        DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
            SELECT table_name
            FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
            WHERE table_schema = 'comments' 
            AND column_name LIKE '%UserId';

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


        OPEN cursor1;
        read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor1 INTO tableName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

      SET stmtFields = CONCAT('`',tableName,'`','.' , columnName ,'=', UserIdValue) ;


     SET @stmtQuery=CONCAT(@sql,'SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM ' ,'`',tableName,'`', ' WHERE ', stmtFields ) ;
   select @stmtQuery;


        END LOOP;

       PREPARE stmt FROM @stmtQuery ;
       EXECUTE stmt ;

       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
       CLOSE cursor1;
END
```

results example   (**select @stmtQuery**):

```
     SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM `basia` WHERE `basia`.UserId=0
     SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM `Comments_11` WHERE `Comments_11`.UserId=0
     ... etc
```

I want get a one results from all this query but know I got only One results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate query in a loop using CONCAT function, add 'UNION' or 'UNION ALL' clause between them, then execute result query with a prepared statements.

***Solution without cursor:***

```
SET @resultQuery = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT
    CONCAT('SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM ', table_name, ' WHERE UserId = ', UserIdValue)
    SEPARATOR '\r\nUNION\r\n'
  )
INTO
  @resultQuery
FROM
  information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
  table_schema = 'comments' AND column_name LIKE '%UserId';

SELECT @resultQuery;
```

It will produce result like this:

```
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM table1 WHERE UserId = 10
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM table2 WHERE UserId = 10
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM table3 WHERE UserId = 10
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM table4 WHERE UserId = 10
...
```

Increase `group_concat_max_len` variable if needed. It is the maximum allowed result length for the GROUP_CONCAT() function, default value = 1024.

Comment: it's easy when I reading your answer but how it do it because I dont know

Comment: It so simple, I see you have used CONCAT function yet, just use this function to biuld your result query - add SELECT and UNION in the loop. I have added another solution, without opening cursor. Check the answer.

Comment: Can You send me the whole procedure with your solution. I will be grateful

Comment: This is working code. `UserIdValue` is procedure parameter, @resultQuery variable contains SELECT query with UNIONs, use prepared statements to execute it. Please explain, what was wrong actually? I'll try to help.

Comment: My code is below. The problem is that the loop runs all the time and do not want to stop. I do not get any results

Comment: You shouldn't use loop in this case, SELECT with GROUP_CONCAT will do everything for you.

Comment: Ok I understand. But If I start this procedure I always get(my help procedure show):


'SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM 0 WHERE UserId = 3
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM 1234 WHERE UserId = 3
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM 2132 WHERE UserId = 3
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM 2147 WHERE UserId = 3
UNION
SELECT'

But I dont get score

Comment: 'SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM `0` WHERE UserId =2
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM `1234` WHERE UserId =2
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM `2132` WHERE UserId =2
UNION
SELECT Nick, Title, Content FROM `2147` WHERE UserId =2
UNION
SE'

Comment: Increase `group_concat_max_len` variable - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: AND I SEE that procedure dont get all tables but only four first tables

Comment: Have you tried to set variable? e.g. SET @@group_concat_max_len = 100000;

Comment: How did you set this variable? It should be set in the same session where the SELECT statement is running. Or change it in ini-file and restart server to set it globally.

Comment: Hm, if you set it in procedure then it had to help.